# How to Use JFileChooser to input CSV filedata into a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jfilechooser, opencsv

I am currently trying to get my program to input data from a user-defined CSV file into a JTable. However, for some reason it doesn't work properly, and Netbeans throws some exceptions into the debugger whenever I try to load or save the file.

```
private void openActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                     
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            // What to do with the file, e.g. display it in a TextArea
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader( file.getAbsolutePath()));
            List myEntries = reader.readAll();
            table (myEntries.toArray());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("problem accessing file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }
}
```

that's my code for the specific problem.

How do I make this work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only the suggestions

1. you can to put [Vector or Object[]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28%29) to the [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) directly
2. for `java.util.List` you have to implements custom [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), because `JTable` and its `XxxTableModel` is based on premature `Vector or Object[]`
3. all updates to the `XxxTableModel` must be done on [EventDispatchThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
4. for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), where contens from `CSV File` should be hardcoded to the `java.util.List` directly
5. all data for `JTable` (view) are stored into `XxxTableModel` (model)